# Rank only the top 10

Tags: excel

I have 20 companies in column B, their respective volume in column C, and finally in column D, I have the % of "yes".

I would like to make a top 10 next to this that wouldn't change whwnever I change the filter on the initial chart. The top 10 would be the top 10 with highest volume ranked in % of "yes".

So per example:

Company A - Volume 10'000 - 50% Yes
Company B - Volume 5'000 - 70% Yes
Company C - Volume 2'000 - 90% Yes.

If per example I only want top 2, I'd want to have another chart with :

1st: 5'000 - 70% yes
2nd: 10'000 - 50% yes

I thought about ranking the 20 companies with the function Rank and then do a VLookup on the other chart. However the problem is that whenever I would need a top 10 ranking for the % of yes ONLY on the top 10 volume companies

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me

Thank you

Comment: Have you thought above using a PivotTable for this? You can set up the PivotTable with % of "yes" as a value field and then set a top 10 value filter using the dropdown arrow for Company.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved my problem. I had found another solution but pretty complicated. Sometimes we don't think enough bout the easy ones. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @lori-m:

[image: SO9767627 example]

The PT could be on a separate sheet but here is below the data sample for the sake of the image. It can't be on the same rows as the sample to ensure it *wouldn't change whenever I change the filter on the initial chart*. The filter in Row1 is only applied down to Row21.

The Value filter in B23 is `1. Company: Top 10 by Sum of Volume`.

`Sum of % Yes` is sorted Largest to Smallest.